# Combining rows into one row

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table

| id | employee | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12345 | 2/1/2022 |
| 2 | 12345 | 2/6/2022 |

Results

| employee | date1 | date2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 2/1/2022 | 2/6/2022 |

How can I write a SQL statement to combine dates from two rows into 1 row grouped by employee?

Comment: What if there are three rows? 25? 7000? Only 1? What version of SQL Server?

Comment: And are those dates in February? (So people don't have to guess, use unambiguous formats.)

Answer (score 3):

-- if there are only two rows per employee:

```
SELECT employee, date1 = MIN(date), date2 = MAX(date)
  FROM dbo.two_rows_only
  GROUP BY employee;
```

-- if there can be more than two rows per employee you can determine which one you want. I assume the two oldest dates:

```
;WITH x AS
(
  SELECT employee, date, rn = ROW_NUMBER() 
    OVER (PARTITION BY employee ORDER BY date)
  FROM dbo.two_rows_only
)
SELECT employee, date1 = [1], date2 = [2]
FROM x
PIVOT 
(
  MAX(date) FOR rn IN ([1],[2])
) AS p;
```

-- example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e613c7b36e6f82990ac3155cb631e570)